# Where do I pay taxes on stocks which I sell from options that are granted to me? (Netherlands, Belgium)

Tags: stocks, netherlands, expatriate, belgium

I am an expat and I travel and move to different countries quite frequently. I am working for a company that plans to IPO at some point soon.

Currently, I am in Belgium, however, I will move to the Netherlands this move permanently to be near my wife's work. As part of my agreement with my current company I will receive stock options.

**My Questions: When will I have to pay taxes on my stock options and in which country? Which taxes do I have to pay? How much will the tax be?**

The text is something like this but I have changed certain details for privacy reasons:

> You will be also eligible to participate in the company’s equity
> program in accordance with company regulations. You would be eligible
> for 10.000 options. Your award will vest and become exercisable 25% on
> the first anniversary of the Grant Date and the remaining 75% in equal
> monthly installments thereafter, with the Options being fully vested
> on the fourth anniversary of the Grant Date, subject to your continued
> service with the Company through the applicable vesting date.

Some important information

1. I struck this agreement while I was in Belgium.
2. I will be in the Netherlands for about 3-5 years.
3. I don't know when I will sell my stocks.
4. I intend to move to Greece permanently.

Comment: I think you usually pay taxes in the country of residence with a few exceptions. However, this is what the Dutch tax authority "Belastingdienst" states about it: https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/standaard_functies/individuals/contact/your_rights_and_obligations/filing_a_tax_return/in_which_country_must_you_file_a_tax_return and https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/en/individuals/content/multiple-countries-double-taxation.